# Como identificar se o usuário está no topo da página?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ao entrar no site a página será exibida a partir do topo *(por padrão)*, como fazer para identificar se a página está no topo usando **JavaScript** puro e **jQuery**?

**Exemplos:**

- Se a página estiver no topo, esconder a `<div id="um-id">`, mas se
  rolar a página para baixo, a `div` aparecer.
- Se a página carregar e rolar diretamente para um elemento com `id`, como `exemplo.com/#rodape` e em seguida o usuário, rolar para o topo, um alerta aparecer.

*Esses são apenas exemplos de uso, a questão é, como identificar se está no topo da pagina usando **JavaScript** e/ou **jQuery**?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Verifique se `$(document).scrollTop()` retorna 0. Se retornar 0, é porque está no topo da página. Se não quiser usar o jQuery, use `document.documentElement.scrollTop`.

---

> Se a página estiver no topo, esconder a `<div id="um-id">`, mas se rolar a página para baixo, a `div` aparecer.

O evento `scroll` pode ser usado para isso. Veja no código abaixo:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $("#um-id").toggle($(document).scrollTop() !== 0);
});
```

```css
.bla {
    height: 200px;
}

#um-id {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="um-id">Teste</div>
<p class="bla">blablablabla</p>
<p class="bla">dadadada</p>
<p class="bla">qwaqwqaqwqa</p>
```

---

> Se a página carregar e rolar diretamente para um elemento com `id`, como `exemplo.com/#rodape` e em seguida o usuário, rolar para o topo, um alerta aparecer.

Nesse daqui, tem que usar a propriedade `elemento.offset().top`para dar uma ajudinha. Veja o código abaixo:

```js
var rodape = $("#rodape");
$(document).scrollTop(rodape.offset().top);
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $("#alerta").toggle($(document).scrollTop() < rodape.offset().top);
});
```

```css
.bla {
    height: 200px;
}

#alerta {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="alerta">Teste</div>
<p class="bla">blablablabla</p>
<p class="bla">dadadada</p>
<p class="bla" id="rodape">AQUI!</p>
<p class="bla">qwaqwqaqwqa</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

***jQuery***

Função: `$(window).scrollTop()`

```
$(document).scroll(function() { 
   if($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
     // Coloque aqui o que você deseja fazer se estiver no topo
   }
});
```